# Network Address Identification

Tags: c#, c, networking, udp, ip

I am trying to implement an application like Skype. I am a little confused if **I will need a server to store the clients machine ip address**, so they know how to locate each other. Or there is some more better technique so the clients machine can locate each other.

I was thinking at UDP multicast, hence the need for the ips. I will be using c# or C, so any code is welcome.

Comment: Have a look a SIP/XMPP servers for getting ideas.

Comment: And no, there is no such feature which allows you to shout into the internet and be heard in the last corner of the net, so you buddy would be able to answer.

Comment: The shout thing would very nice. Just imagine self aware network living apps = ]. You are right, the SIP/XMPP specifications have good ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the IP addresses on the server, the computers will connect to the server. The server should associate states to IP addresses, like Active, Idle, Busy and stuff and the client should get the list of users accordingly. Messages should be sent to the server, which, in turn would forward them to the recipient(s).

Comment: Is there a way to implement some kind of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroreception#Electrolocation Electrolocation. I mean, my application when connected would send a live signal that would be only knowable by other clients with specific signature

Comment: Could you please elaborate more why the server has to the middle ware.

Comment: Because you do not know what places you want to reach. If I understood you correctly, you want "secret chat". If that is the case, you can encrypt the content of the message upon sending and decrypt on the server. At least when the connection is initialized. If you want a direct communication, you can send the addresses to the clients from the server, but the server is needed anyway to initiate the connection.

Comment: Ok, I was thinking about performance issues, but since nowadays 10MB+ connections are more common, I think we can find more machines able to be used as servers. For example, the skype group creator would be the server machine, the clients would send messages through a streaming channel, the hosting machine would "multicast" the message to the other connected clients. SignalR does that, but it is for small messages, not for VoIP.